override order of items drawn within the same z index
An extension of this question,
I tried creating the custom property called depth similar to y sort where the higher the depth value the more "in front" the image is drawn.

So far I've used GDExtension and followed how y sort collects children nodes & sorts the nodes as such:
void GDExample::sort_children_by_depth()
{
    // get top most node (sort_node) whose children are to be sorted
    GDExample *sort_node = this;
    GDExample *parent_node = (GDExample *)sort_node->get_parent();

    while (parent_node && parent_node->get_class() == this->get_class())
    {
        sort_node = parent_node;
        parent_node = (GDExample *)parent_node->get_parent();
    }


    // get children of `sort_node` from every level
    int children_count = 1; // 1 since including `sort_node`
    _collect_depth_children(sort_node, nullptr, children_count);
    GDExample **child_items = (GDExample **)alloca((children_count) * sizeof(GDExample *));
    child_items[0]=sort_node;


    // to store all children into child_items
    children_count = 1;
    _collect_depth_children(sort_node, child_items, children_count);


    // sort all nodes based on their depth
    SortArray<GDExample *, DepthSort> sorter;
    sorter.sort(child_items, children_count);


    // get the index of `sort_node`
    int sort_node_index=-1;
    for(int i=0; i<children_count;i++){
        if(child_items[i]==sort_node){
            sort_node_index=i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // >how do I replace the below segment by flattening the items into a single z index?
    //
    for(int i=0; i<children_count;i++) // assigning z index relative to `sort_node`
        child_items[i]->set_z_index(i - sort_node_index);
}

and this works by setting the z index as needed but I'm trying to "flatten" all the images into a single z index like in y sort, I've traced the "flattening" process to _attach_canvas_item_for_draw where I guess r_z_list and r_z_last_list handle the order of drawing items
within the same z index but I have no idea how to implement this in my own code.
so ultimately, how do I handle the order of items drawn within the same index? (or any other approach with similar effect?)

Update:
I tried using canvas_item_set_draw_index & set_as_top_level and seems to give the desired effect for sorting but now the children don't follow the parent transform nor do visual properties such as modulate propagate down
for (int i = 0; i < children_count; i++){
    child_items[i]->set_as_top_level(true);
    RenderingServer::get_singleton()->canvas_item_set_draw_index(child_items[i]->get_canvas_item(), i - sort_node_index);
}

